# When crafting an item does the check need to exceed the cost before or after paying 1/3 materials?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

Sorry for the complicated question title, it was very difficult to phrase.

According to [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft/), when crafting an item you first must pay 1/3 of the raw material cost. Following that, you must make a check to see if you successfully craft the item and how long doing so will take. If your check x the DC beats the cost of the item (in sp), then the item is made within that week of crafting.

My question is: To craft the item within at least one week, does your check need to beat the original sp cost of the raw materials? Or the cost after you have already paid 1/3?

Answer (score 4):

### The original item's price

The Craft skill gives us some guidelines on how to calculate the raw material cost and the time spent crafting an item:

> To determine how much time and money it takes to make an item, follow these steps.
>
> - Find the **item’s price** in silver pieces (1 gp = 10 sp).
> - Find the item’s DC from Table: Craft Skills.
> - **Pay 1/3 of the item’s price** for the raw material cost.
> - Make an appropriate Craft check representing one week’s worth of work. If the check succeeds, multiply your check result by the DC. If the result × the DC equals the **price of the item in sp**, then you have completed the item. (If the result × the DC equals double or triple the price of the item in silver pieces, then you’ve completed the task in one-half or one-third of the time.  Other multiples of the DC reduce the time in the same manner.) If the result × the DC doesn’t equal the price, then it represents the progress you’ve made this week. Record the result and make a new Craft check for the next week. Each week, you make more progress until **your total reaches the price of the item in silver pieces**.

As you can see, all calculations are done on the item's original price converted to silver pieces.

Also, this [handy crafting calculator](http://viajon.net/pf/crafting/) should help you figuring out the cost and time spent.

Comment: +1'd for the calculator, or else I'd have given it to the short and sweet one from Shadocat

Answer (score 3):

You always start out using the full price of the item when determining progress.

Look at the order of actions in the PFSRD.

First you pay 1/3 the total cost of the item.  Presumably for raw materials.

Then make a roll.

If successful then divide the week by the multiplier of the success (1/2 a week if you rolled 2x DC).  That is how long that step took.  Then note the roll result times the DC and keep a running tally.  Repeat this until the tally equals or exceeds the full price of the item in sp.